# How to make huge loops in python faster on mac?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, loops, cpu-usage

I am a computer science student and some of the things I do require me to run huge loops on Macbook with dual core i5. Some the loops take 5-6 hours to complete but they only use 25% of my CPU. Is there a way to make this process faster? I cant change my loops but is there a way to make them run faster?

Thank you

Mac OS 10.11
Python 2.7 (I have to use 2.7) with IDLE or Spyder on Anaconda

Here is a sample code that takes 15 minutes:

```
def test_false_pos():
    sumA = [0] * 1000
    for test in range(1000):
        counter = 0
        bf = BloomFilter(4095,10)
        for i in range(600):
            bf.rand_inserts()
        for x in range(10000):
            randS = str(rnd.randint(0,10**8))
            if bf.lookup(randS):
                counter += 1
        sumA[test] = counter/10000.0
    avg = np.mean(sumA)
    return avg
```

Comment: do you have 4 processor?

Comment: @StevenG: (S)he said, "Macbook with dual core i5".

Comment: @tTIKA please learn more about `Iterators` and `Generators` from [here](http://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/igd.html)

Comment: dual core with hyper threading - 4 cores. which is why 25%. but yeah, in order to make this faster you can try a couple of things: `multiprocessing` or play around with `numpy`

Comment: No its not hyperthreded. Only physical 2 cores

Comment: @Avi I skimmed through the link but cant really understand what they are. Can u explain it please?

Comment: basically `a generator is a special routine that can be used to control the iteration behaviour of a loop`; and for iterator, have a look at this [`link`](https://www.codementor.io/python/tutorial/python-generators-and-iterators)

Answer (score 4):

Sure thing: Python 2.7 has to generate huge lists and waste a lot of memory *each time* you use `range(<a huge number>)`.

Try to use the `xrange` function instead. It doesn't create that gigantic list at once, it produces the members of a sequence *lazily*.

---

But if your were to use Python 3 (which is the modern version and the future of Python), you'll find out that there `range` is even cooler and faster than `xrange` in Python 2.

Comment: `xrange` saves *memory*, it's not necessarily going to speed up execution. You still have to call `next` on each iteration; that call just computes the next value rather than pulling it from a list.

Comment: @chepner, well, even allocating such a tremendous amount of memory and filling it with a lot of data just to loop over it (this is what Python 2's `range` does) wastes much time.

Comment: 10000 integers is not a "tremendous" amount of memory. The question is how much time does each Bloom filter operation take relative to the loop overhead. As with anything, benchmark to find out.

Comment: I just tried just the loops of the 15 minutes sample code (with `pass` in them). Took less than one second. You really think that's noticeable at all?

Comment: To be more precise: It took about 0.17 seconds with `range` and 0.13 seconds with `xrange`. That's only 0.04 seconds improvement.

Comment: @StefanPochmann How did you tried it with out having my Bloom Filter class? I though that operation was the expensive part.

Comment: @tTIKA Exactly like I described.

Answer (score 3):

You could split it up into 4 loops:

```
import multiprocessing

def test_false_pos(times, i, q):
    sumA = [0] * times
    for test in range(times):
        counter = 0
        bf = BloomFilter(4095,10)
        for i in range(600):
            bf.rand_inserts()
        for x in range(10000):
            randS = str(rnd.randint(0,10**8))
            if bf.lookup(randS):
                counter += 1
        sumA[test] = counter/10000.0
    q.put([i, list(sumA)])

def full_test(pieces):
    threads = []
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    steps = 1000 / pieces
    for i in range(pieces):
        threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=test_false_pos, args=(steps, i, q)))
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    results = [None] * pieces
    for i in range(pieces):
        i, result = q.get()
        results[i] = result
    # Flatten the array (`results` looks like this: [[...], [...], [...], [...]])
    # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5244995
    sums = [value for result in results for val in result]
    return np.mean(np.array(sums))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    full_test(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

This will run *n* processes that each do 1/*n*th of the work, where *n* is the number of processors on your computer.

The `test_false_pos` function has been modified to take three parameters:

- `times` is the number of times to run the loop.
- `i` is passed through to the result.
- `q` is a queue to add the results to.

The function loops `times` times, then places `i` and `sumA` into the queue for further processing.

The main thread (`full_test`) waits for each thread to complete, then places the results in the appropriate position in the `results` list. Once the list is complete, it is flattened, and the mean is calculated and returned.

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time im seeng this. So to call the function, do I call full_test or test_false_pos? And with what arguments?

Comment: @tTIKA You call `full_test`, and pass it the number of separate processes you want.

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan I’ve added an explanation. How does it look?

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking into Numba and Jit (just in time compiler).  It works for functions that are Numpy based.  It can handle some python routines, but is mainly for speeding up numerical calculations, especially ones with loops (like doing cholesky rank-1 up/downdates).  I don't think it would work with a BloomFilter, but it is generally super helpful to know about.

In cases where you must use other packages in your flow with numpy, separate out the heavy-lifting numpy routines into their own functions, and throw a @jit decorator on top of that function.  Then put them into your flows with normal python stuff.